# Why don't we use super in front of render method in React

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and was learning components. What confused me is that why we do not use super in front of render method after inherited from React.Component. Here is the example:

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  super.render() {
    return <div style={{ color: this.props.color }}>{this.props.children}</div>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, `super.render()` is invalid syntax when declared like that. I assume you meant:

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div style={{ color: this.props.color }}>{this.props.children}</div>;
  }
}
```

?

If that's the case, that's because React.Component doesn't provide a render method in the superclass. You can see [from the source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js#L21) that the `React.Component` class only provides some standardised behaviour around `setState()` and `forceUpdate()`.

Comment: thanks for your kind answer, what kind of behavior method should have to be invoked with super in front?

Comment: You should call `super.methodName()` when you absolutely need to call the method named `methodName` in the superclass (i.e, making sure you aren't calling a method declared with the same name on the current class) or when you're overriding a method in the parent class and want to retain the original behaviour (which you usually do). You should always call `super()` in constructors extending from a base class because those have behaviour you must maintain to avoid the object being in a corrupt state

Answer (score 0):

Well, `render` is not a method call. It's a declaration inside a class. Therefore it cannot have any kind of dot notation. You cannot select an instance on which it should be called because you are not calling it, you are declaring it.

`super` is generally used to call the method implementation of the parent class, *from inside* method bodies.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `React.Component` is an internal React class meanwhile `super` is a method that allows you to call parents methods.

You most likely never want to call any particular `React.Component` method since (at least as far as I know) none of them is intended for explicit usage.

So, almost the only situation when you need to call `super` inside a class that extends `React.Component` is when you want to have a `constructor` inside your component. In this case you need to call `super(props)` in order to pass props to parent's class constructor.

In case you don't have a custom `constructor` function, the parent (`React.Component`) `constructor` will be used by default.

[Here's](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor) additional documentation for React-specific part.